# best interface for opencv

Tags: opencv

I've started learning opencv and it provides api's for Java,python,c++.
which one is better? Which one has better documentation and probability of finding a particular solution is high?

Comment: I think they are equal, use which is more siple for you

Comment: In Python it is easier to find additional packages which are using the same datatypes. So if you need more than just pure OpenCV stuff I would go with Python. Java I have never tried.

Comment: I guess you'll find most code samples for c++ and maybe python

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say which language is the best, but definitely in your case Java is the worst choice:

- Comparing to C++ and Python, Java documentation is poor
- Python and c++ has a lot of (realy good!) examples or even whole projects
- OpenCV developers are focused on "original" version (c++) and the most popular wrapper, which is Python. There is much bigger chance that you will find some bug in Java wrapper than in C++/Python version

Generally, when you are starting to learn something new, try to choose the most popular version (and the easiest to use) - most likely you will have a lot of questions and using the most popular version will make finding answers much easier.

Choosing between c++ and python is definitely not as obvious as decision to foreget about java.
If you know only one of those 2 languages - choose this one - you will not have to waste your time on learning another one.
If you don't know any of them - i would suggest you to start with python, it's easier to learn - you can focuse on solving problems, not on memory managment, converting types, etc. C++ is really good language and there is nothing wrong in memrory managment etc, but in my opinion it's much easier to start with python and than eventually move to c++.
If you know c++ and python - it's not easy decision, right know i'm working on a project in which i'm using my framework which allows me to use modules written in c++ or python (one module - one language, but different modules can be in different languages) and this solution is almost perfect (there are some issues with converting data between c++ and python parts). I think that there is more tutorials for c++ and it's easier to find some computer vision specific libraryies (like OpenCV blobs or implementation of Tracking Learning Detection algorithm) in c++, but python has numpy and some other great libs too - in my opinion they are "equal", so it's all up to you and your preferences.